# Can a neural network be of variable depth?

Tags: neural-network, theory

It is very common for neural networks to be asymmetric about the x axis, that is, to have many more nuerons in the first few layers than in the last few layers. [Common example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk#t=1m46s):

[image]

But can neural networks be structured in such a way that they're asymmetric about the *y axis*, that is, such that some parts of the network are 'deeper' than others?

An example of where this could be useful is where a problem involves some unsophisticated features (that require only a small number of layers), and some much more sophisticated features (which may benefit greatly from having more layers - i.e. greater 'depth').

Answer (score 1):

#### "Wide and Deep network"  was used in a 2016 paper.

[image]

$\hspace{5cm}$*Wide & Deep Learning for Recommender Systems*

You may create using keras *Concatenate layer*

```py
concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()([input, hidden2])
```

**References to read -**

[The paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07792.pdf)

[Google blog](https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/06/wide-deep-learning-better-together-with.html)

[Another paper](http://oro.open.ac.uk/51726/1/322.pdf)